# Rails Form Submission Blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on my rails app form:

```
          <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-header">
                <strong>Add Contact</strong>
              </div>     

        <% if @contact.errors.any? %>
           <div class="alert alert-danger">
               <h3>Please correct the following:</h3>
                  <ul>
                   <% @contact.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                       <li> <%= message %></li>
                   <% end %>
                  </ul>
           </div>
        <% end %>

     <%= form_for(@contact, html: {multipart: true}) do |f| %>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9">



                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :name, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :name, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :email, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.email_field :email, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                     <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :phone, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :mobile, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :mobile, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                     <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :company, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :company, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group row">
                       <%= f.label :address, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                         <%= f.text_area :address, class: "form-control", rows: 3%>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :city, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :city, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :state, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :state, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :country, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :country, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                    </div>

                 <div class="form-group row">
                      <%= f.label :zip, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-8">
                        <%= f.text_field :zip, class: "form-control"%>
                      </div>
                </div>





                    <div class="form-group row">
                     <%= f.label :group_id, class: "col-md-3 col-form-label"%>
                      <div class="col-md-5">
                          <%= f.collection_select :group_id, Group.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Select Group" }, class: "form-control" %>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-3">
                        <a href="#" id="add-group-btn" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-block">Add Group</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group row" id="add-new-group">
                      <div class="offset-md-3 col-md-8">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="group_id" placeholder="Enter group name" aria-label="Enter group name" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
                          <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2">
                              <i class="fa fa-check"></i>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>


                  <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="fileinput fileinput-new" data-provides="fileinput">
                      <div class="fileinput-new img-thumbnail" style="width: 150px; height: 150px;">
                        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150"  alt="...">
                      </div>
                      <div class="fileinput-preview fileinput-exists img-thumbnail" style="max-width: 150px; max-height: 150px;"></div>
                      <div class="mt-2">
                        <span class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-file"><span class="fileinput-new">Select image</span><span class="fileinput-exists">Change</span><input type="file" name="..."></span>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary fileinput-exists" data-dismiss="fileinput">Remove</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
              <div class="card-footer">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-8">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</a>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

<% end %>
```

And here's my model:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group

  validates :name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :company, :address, :city, :state, :country, :zip, :group_id, presence: true
  validates :name, length: {  maximum: 50 }
  validates :email, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :phone, length: { maximum: 15 }
  validates :mobile, length: {  maximum: 15 }

  def gravatar
    hash = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(email.downcase)
    "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{hash}"
  end 
end
```

When I select the group and filled up everything on the for I am still getting the ff errors:

```
Please correct the following:
Group must exist
Group can't be blank
```

I am not sure what's preventing from submission since I submitted and selected the group when I click "save". I also did check the f.collection field if its properly initiated but still getting the error.

Any idea what's causing this?

[image]

UPDATE:

Here's my controllers code:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  def index

    if params[:group_id] && !params[:group_id].empty?
      @contacts = Contact.where(group_id: params[:group_id]).order(:created_at, :desc).page params[:page]
    else 
      @contacts = Contact.order(:created_at, :desc).page params[:page]
  end
end 

def new
  @contact = Contact.new
end 

def create
  @contact = Contact.new(contact_params)
  if @contact.save
    flash[:success] = "Contact was successfully created."
    redirect_to contacts_path
  else
    render 'new' 
  end
end 

private

def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :company, :address, :city, :state, :country, :zip)
end 


end
```

And here's the log from the terminal after submission:

```
Started POST "/contacts" for ::1 at 2019-12-14 19:26:30 +0800
Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MsG6nNpJfDSiOHjoUP/TUenhzyIlXlftSxY9xY7q8vkrmQJMUK471gr+8wQmQ8STNoE6kTHTQzM1gC1UUKbO5Q==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Samuel", "email"=>"samuel@gmail.com", "phone"=>"99999", "mobile"=>"99999", "company"=>"KASdasd", "address"=>"2015-B", "city"=>"ANgeles", "state"=>"Pampanga", "country"=>"Philippines", "zip"=>"9000", "group_id"=>"16"}, "group_id"=>""}
Unpermitted parameter: :group_id
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:17
   (0.5ms)  rollback transaction
  ↳ app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:17
  Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Group Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"
  ↳ app/views/contacts/new.html.erb:109
  Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (17.9ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (1.1ms)
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts"
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb:8
  CACHE Group Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups"
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb:13
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."group_id" = ?  [["group_id", 15]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb:18
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."group_id" = ?  [["group_id", 16]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb:18
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."group_id" = ?  [["group_id", 17]]
  ↳ app/views/layouts/_sidebar.html.erb:18
  Rendered layouts/_sidebar.html.erb (8.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 166ms (Views: 147.9ms | ActiveRecord: 1.7ms)
```

Comment: Can you please post your controller code as well as any server logs that come through when you try and submit (the parameters it receives)

Comment: Mark: Please check my updates above.

Answer (score 1):

`Unpermitted parameter: :group_id` in the server logs is your clue. As the group_id isn't in the list of params you permit in the below code, it never gets assigned, so it thinks you haven't selected a group.

Change

```
def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :company, :address, :city, :state, :country, :zip)
end
```

To

```
def contact_params
   params.require(:contact).permit(:name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :company, :address, :city, :state, :country, :zip, :group_id)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by adding :group_id to the params whitelist:

```
params.require(:contact)
      .permit(
        :name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :company, :address, 
        :city, :state, :country, :zip, :group_id
      )
```

A pro-tip is to NOT write your entire whitelist on one single line.

You should also remove the extra presence validation:

```
validates :name, :email, :phone, :mobile, :company, :address, 
          :city, :state, :country, :zip, presence: true
```

`belongs_to` adds a validation by default in Rails 5+. This removes the superfluous "Group can't be blank" error message.

And you can do a lot better when handling nested routes:

```
class ContactsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /contacts
  # GET /groups/:group_id/contacts
  def index
    if params[:group_id].present?
      @group = Group.includes(:contacts).find(group_id)
      @contacts = @group.contacts
    else
      @contacts = Contact.all
    end
  end
end
```

That will properly give a 404 if the group id provided in the params does not exist.